# Doctrine 2 custom type

Tags: symfony, types, doctrine-orm

I am trying to follow the example at
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html
and create a custom quantity type. Everything works fine when quantity type is defined as:

```
class Quantity extends Type
{
 const QUANTITY = 'quantity'; // modify to match your type name

 public function getSqlDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
 {
    return 'decimal(10,2)';
 }

 public function getName()
 {
    return self::QUANTITY;
 }
```

}

However when introducting

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return $value->toDecimal();
}
```

I get the following error when saving:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function toDecimal() on a non-object in ...\Types\Quantity.php line 26

Comment: I suspect that the "return $value->toDecimal();" is for demonstration reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$value` you get is either `string` or `null`. You can't call `toDecimal` on it. Try:

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
    return $value === null ? null : (float) $value;
}
```